# collapsingtoolbar get error with afollestad-material-dialogs

Tags: dialog, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to use [this dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) in my apps because these can change direction of multiple choice list. I have CollapsingToolbarLayout in my app too, but when I add this lib to my gradle file this error happens. what can I do?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: ir.yasin.dordaneh.shahre_namha, PID: 6940 android.view.InflateException:
Binary XML file line #138: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
at ...
```

Answer (score 0):

finaly I got my answer. I just use another collapsingtoolbar library from android arsenal like [this](https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar) .